# Calculating discharge time of 12V LED light powered by AA batteries

Tags: led, power, batteries, power-consumption

I just want to check up my assumption on power consumption of six 12V LED lights in parallel connection. So I powered it by 8 AA (E91 energizer) batteries in series.

The LED's ideal forward current is 80 mA for good lighting.

$$6 \times 80mA = 480mA$$

That's based on the [datasheet](http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/E91.pdf) (milliamp - hour capacity).

Is it correct if I assume it can power the 6 LEDs in parallel for \$\dfrac{1500}{480} = 3.125 hrs\$?

Additional question: Is there any way I can keep the LED brightness at optimal level (not affected by the exhausting batteries)?

Answer (score 1):

If they are 12 volt LEDs then why are you powering them at 9V nominal (6x 1.5 volt batteries)? Assuming this is a typo or can be otherwise explained, look at page 2 of your battery's data sheet - it tells you how you can expect the battery to perform when taking a constant power from it.

I think you'll get slightly less than 1 hour from the battery at a ~500mA discharge with the terminal voltage dropping from 1.5 volts to 1.2 volts (top right graph).

If you want to keep brightness more constant then consider using a boost regulator.

Comment: Yeh. It's 8 batteries (typo!).... what's the boost regulator??? Sorry i just get into this stuff. This is the led: http://www.lightinthebox.com/g4-3w-240-270lm-3000-3500k-warm-white-light-resin-led-corn-bulb-12v_p486455.html?pos=ultimately_buy_2

Comment: In its basic form it's described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter - it uses an inductor to create a larger voltage than what is being fed in to it but, clearly, for the same power out it must take more current BUT, it could produce 12V (obviously this needs to be current regulated for the LEDs) from a supply as low as 3 volts and as high as maybe 10 volts. A buck-boost regulator can take maybe 3V to 20V and give out 12v.

Comment: You know any boost regulator out there that suit for my circuit? I'm new to this stuff and a search on google just overwhelmed me

Comment: Texas instruments and Linear technology have good parametric search engines. Try Linear tech first and see what it comes up with. Use input voltage range of 6 volts to 14 volts with an output of 12 volts at the current you need.

Comment: Look for `boost converter LM2577 -XL6009` on eBay (you have to strip out the XL6009 stuff -- they might work, but they don't  give specs in the listings, so I don't trust them); you'll find lots of cheap Chinese-made boost converters. The first one I pulled up says it can provide 12V/800mA from a 5V source, so you can use 4xAA (or two 4xAA sets in parallel for more runtime), then tune the converter via trimpot to slightly less than 12V so the LEDs self-regulate their current draw.

Answer (score 1):

You want to get constant current at 12V to run the LED's from 1.5V batteries.

You will need a boost converter, as others have suggested, to raise the 1.5V to 12V. Power conversions are not ideal, and all voltage-changing devices consume/waste some of the input voltage doing their job. The constant-current chart in the data-sheet is meaningless since a boost converter draws a variable amount of current at a variable frequency and/or duty-cycle.

At the LED's, what you are asking for is:

```
Constant voltage(E) * constant current(I) = constant power (P)
```

Regardless of the conversion method, you will require the same input **power** from the battery as you want the LED's to output. Boost converters are very efficient, but do have associated losses.

```
Pbattery = PboostLoss + Pled
```

and

```
P = I * E
```

So, for a boost converter to draw a constant P from the battery, as E decreases, I must increase, discharging the battery even faster, causing its voltage to drop faster, etc., etc. That is the reason there is not an easy or definitive answer as to how long they will last for your application. LTSpice is helpful for time-integrating things like this but I'm not sure if you can model a AA battery's discharge properly.

There are only two "absolutes" I can think of for this question:

1. In identical circuits, twice as many batteries in parallel will run for twice as long. Batteries discharge constant power, together.
2. Twice as many batteries in series will require less intense and/or frequent boosting to reach 12V, reducing switching losses. Batteries discharge constant power, together.

======

A boost converter: https://www.pololu.com/product/799

Comparison: https://www.pololu.com/search/compare/132

When you go looking for similar trinkets, check SparkFun, Adafruit, and Pololu first!

Comment: From the OP "So I powered it by 8 AA (E91 energizer) batteries in series."

Answer (score 1):

The time it takes for the batteries to discharge is mAh(capacity of one battey)/480mA.Your answer is right.If you want to keep your LEDs at constant brightness,you could try using a joule thief.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it correct if I assume it can power the 6 LEDs in parallel for 1500480=3.125hrs

Not exactly.

First, based on the pictures and provided specs, these led bulbs each have 8 parallel circuits of 3 LEDs and 1 resistor. For 1W @ 12V, that means 80 mA, or 10mA each. Assuming 3.3V Forward Voltage, that means a resistor of (12V - (3.3Vf * 3)) / 0.01A = 210 Ohms. With a constant resistor, but declining Voltage, Current through the bulb will also decline, making the resulting expected life of the battery a curve.

As it so have it, 8 210 Ohm resistors in parallel means a 31.25 Ohm load per bulb, and 8 bulbs in parallel is about 3.2 Ohms. BUT as this is 3 LEDs with a resistor, there is a limit to how low the voltage can go and still light the LEDs. In practice, anything below 10V will be too low for lighting. That means 2V, divided by 8 batteries, is a drop of 0.25V. We will use 0.3V as the datasheets provide a 1.2V drain point.

You have noticed in the datasheet page 1 that a 500mA constant drain to put the expected capacity of the battery at 1500mAh. That's close enough to your load to be accurate for your needs. But the datasheet also provides some real life graphs.

The first graph on the right shows Constant Current Performance to three drain voltages. A 500mA load draining the batteries to 1.2V in just under 1 Hour. Drains to 0.8V in just over 2 hours.

But the other graph, upper right of Industry Standard Test shows a Light draw of 3.3 Ohms, which provides a more accurate graph. As stated above, the current draw changes as the battery drains. A battery with a 3.3 Ohm load drains to 1.2V in 2 hours, to 0.8V in 7 hours.

**So in practice, for lighting down to a 0.3V drain on each battery, you will get about 2 hours of solid light.**

> Is there any way I can keep the LED brightness at optimal level (not affected by the exhausting batteries)

As a ballast resistor setup fluctuates based on input voltage, and direct batteries fluctuate said voltage, you need to step up the voltage. **A step-up, or boost, switching regulator** can do this. Keeping in mind the 80~90% efficiency, you can get an hour or so more of solid lighting before the batteries are completely drained for practical purposes (0.8V is dead dead for Alkaline 1.5V batteries). You can go even more by using an extreme version of the step-up switching regulator, and that is **a Joule Thief circuit.**

Answer (score 0):

The LEDs you mentioned don't need Constant Current as they are designed to work on 12v and contain the necessary resistors. You can use a simple Step-up regulator like Doktor mentioned in a comment earlier. I would be ok with the XL6009 based regulators from ebay since their specification seems to be adequate. Check youtube, there is a video of someone building a 50W led light from a XL6009 regulator. These cheap regulators will power the LEDs with constant brightness as long as the batteries have enough juice left in them, regardless of the dropping voltage.

Check and adjust the output voltage to 12V before connecting the LEDs, just to be safe as these step-up modules can output voltage much more than the LEDs can handle.

Answer (score -1):

You need constant current for the LEDs. The best way to maximize battery life is to use a DC-DC converter that supplies a constant current. Cheapest solution - an LED driver from eBay

Comment: BTW, if you are not using a resistor to limit current from the batteries you may damage the LEDs. Running high brightness LEDs from a battery resistor combination is not the best way to do it.

Comment: You could edit that comment right into the answer, @Dirk...

Comment: But the Voltage will also decay right? So to keep the brightness constant, I need to keep Voltage or current? or both?

Comment: Using a resistor to limit the current will waste power as heat in the resistor, using a constant-current regulator / LED driver circuit would be most efficient.

Comment: Brightness is a function of current and not voltage. You need a switching current driver for efficiency reasons. The input voltage will keep on lowering as the batteries drain but the output voltage will be maintained at such a level that the desired current is achieved.